# Get values of survival function in SAS

Tags: sas

I generated a random sample from an exponential distribution and sorted them so they are going from lowest to highest value, giving me my order statistics. Now I need to get the values of the survival function at these numbers and plot them against the order statistics. I cannot seem to figure out how to get the list of these survival values in SAS, so I can plot them.

Comment: could you migrate it to the stack overflow then? thanks!

Comment: if you are drawing from a exponential distribution, then the survival function, S(x) = exp(- m*x), where 1/m is the mean.

Answer (score 0):

Survivor function estimates at the observed event times can be obtained from the LIFETEST procedure in SAS.

```
proc lifetest data = yourdata outsurv = survest;
    time time2event*eventindicator(0);
run;
```

The output dataset created by the OUTSURV= option contains the survivor function estimates. Note that by default this gives the Kaplan-Meier estimate of the survivor function.

A plot of the estimated survivor function across time is produced automatically by LIFETEST. If you want to plot against order statistics, use the STEP statement in the SGPLOT procedure after computing your order statistics.

```
proc sgplot data = survandorder;
    step x = order y = survival;
run;
```